# Change the background color of command line in zsh when I change the prompt theme

Tags: command-line, themes, colors, zsh

I installed the zsh package.

Also, I downloaded the [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/) framework to customize zsh. When I change theme name in `.zshrc` file to one of the themes given [here](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Themes), it changes the color/type of prompt among other things but the background color stays the same. I want the background color to change to the ones given on that theme wiki page.

So, how do I do change the background color automatically to the ones on that page whenever I change my theme?

Answer (score 4):

For example, I changed in `~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/example.zsh-theme` file the line:

```
PROMPT="%{$fg[red]%}%n%{$reset_color%}@%{$fg[blue]%}%m %{$fg[yellow]%}%~ %{$reset_color%}%% "
```

with the line:

```
PROMPT="%{$bg[cyan]%}%{$fg[red]%}%n%{$reset_color%}%{$bg[cyan]%}@%{$fg[red]%}%m %{$fg[yellow]%}%~ %{$reset_color%}%{$bg[cyan]%}%% "
```

And look what happened:

[image: zsh]

So, I suggest you to play in the same manner with which theme do you wish from  `~/.oh-my-zsh/themes` directory.

Comment: Note unless you set `RPROMPT='%{$reset_color%}'` any command output to the terminal will also carry that background color.  I guess it depends on whether you want all lines to have the same color or if you just want the prompt line to have a different color.  (Personally I wanted to keep my terminal's default BG color but change the prompt line.)

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your terminal and there click on preferences option, it will open a new window; in the new window goto tab colors and there uncheck the checkbox "Use colors from system theme", doing this will load the background of your theme, we can also change further stylings from here. [Image of prefrences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBh4e.png)

Comment: 10 years later... this is the correct answer.